# Flash AS3 based Website - put a different color to each menu

Tags: flash, actionscript

I make a website  based on a tutorial from ActiveTuts.

Here's my code :

```
var navArray:Array=["HOME", "WORK", "MOVIES", "ABOUT", "CONTACT"];

for (var i:Number=0; i<4; i++) {
    var navItem:NavItem=new NavItem  ;
    navItem.x=navItem.width*i;
    navItem.nav_name.text=navArray[i];

    buttonArray.push(navItem);
    navItem.addListeners();
    navContainer.addChild(navItem);
    navItem.name=String(i);
    navItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onNavClick);
}
```

I would like put a color on each menu.

http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/web-design/create-a-full-screen-scalable-flash-website-part-1/

it's in the second video.

here it's my complete code:

```
// INITIAL VARIABLES

var buttonArray:Array = new Array( );
var currentButton:Object=new Object  ;


// ADD NAVIGATION CONTAINER

var navContainer:Sprite=new Sprite  ;
addChild(navContainer);

// NAMES OF BUTTONS

var navArray:Array=["HOME", "WORK", "MOVIES", "ABOUT", "CONTACT"];

// ADD ALL THE BUTTONS WITH A FOR LOOP

for (var i:Number=0; i<5; i++) {
    var navItem:NavItem=new NavItem  ;

    navItem.x=navItem.width*i;
    navItem.nav_name.text=navArray[i];
    buttonArray.push(navItem);
    navItem.addListeners();

    navContainer.addChild(navItem);

    navItem.name=String(i);

    navItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onNavClick);

}

function onNavClick(evt:MouseEvent):void {

    // PREVIOUS BUTTON  
    currentButton.y = 0;
    currentButton.addListeners();
    currentButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onNavClick);

    // NEXT BUTTON
        currentButton = evt.target;
        currentButton.removeListeners();
        currentButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onNavClick);
}

// INITIAL STATE OF NAVIGATION

initialNavigation();

function initialNavigation():void {

    buttonArray[0].y=-10;
    currentButton=buttonArray[0];
    currentButton.removeListeners();
    currentButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onNavClick);

}
```

and now the navItem code:

```
// FORMAT TEXTFIELD
nav_name.autoSize=TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
nav_name.selectable=false;

// POSITION TEXT ACCORDING TO IT'S WIDTH
nav_name.x=224-nav_name.width-15;
nav_name.mouseEnabled=false;

// ROLL OVER

function onOver(evt:MouseEvent):void {

    TweenLite.to(this, 0.2, { y:-10});
    trace("OVER");
}

function onOut(evt:MouseEvent):void {

    TweenLite.to(this, 0.2, { y:0});
}

function addListeners():void {

    this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onOver);
    this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, onOut);
}

function removeListeners():void {

    this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onOver);
    this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, onOut);
}
```

i try to do like CGa says, it's ok for the colour but now my "addlisteners" doesn't work anymore

Comment: Can you post your NavItem code? Probably be useful if you linked to the tutorial also.

Comment: http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/web-design/create-a-full-screen-scalable-flash-website-part-1/

it's in the second video.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what NavItem is. I looked into the tutorial you mentioned and I know assume it is a button created with the flash ide. This button is of the Button class from the flash ide, it got a four frames containing the button states. If you want to change the colour of these buttons, I suggest creating four of them, each having it's own colour.

Answer (score 0):

I could not see the tutorial but what you could do is:

1. Give colour to the text: navItem.nav_name.textColor = 0xCC0000; (This one is red..., 0x000000 is black, etc.)
2. If navItem is a movieclip and has no animations, open it, create four frames, add a stop(); to the first frame. Then you could add to the code you have pasted:

navItem.gotoAndStop(i + 1);

If you choose to do this, you should make sure that the navItem's nav_name can be reached in every frame that you have created.

I hope this helps, I would be more help if I could see the tutorial...

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answers.

here is the link to the tutorial I mentioned:

http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/web-design/create-a-full-screen-scalable-flash-website-part-1/

it's in the second video.

and "navItem" is a movieclip without animations >> i will try to create four frames in it as CGA says

Comment: You should really update your question with this information rather than posting it as an answer.